# Fans speeding up to max at regular intervals, leading to forced shutdowns

Tags: windows, laptop, ssd, shutdown, fan

This is happening on a plugged in laptop, I know it's the fans because I have an SSD, at regular intervals the fan will go full throttle for like 15 seconds and then the system shuts down. I've ran disk checks and memory checks to no avail. I ran disk cleanup and wiped my browser cache and that only made the intervals between each shutdown wider. However the issue did not occur when booting in safe mode (with networking) I tried using resource monitor to see if the GPU was being overloaded but that was not the case, nothing unusual was going on even while the fans were in high gear.

Running Windows on a Lenovo Legion with Intel Core i7-7700 2.8 GHz with a Geforce 1060

Comment: I have not had issues with thermal compound on Lenovo machines.  Use something like Real Temp to see what is overheating. You may need to get the machine serviced.

Comment: As this is not happening in Safe mode, the problem is with some installed software. Run deep antivirus checks, using at least your installed antivirus and also [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/). If nothing is found, test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: The virus scans aren't returning anything and Dism/Online/Cleanup-image/Restorehealth is returning that the 'Cleanup-image' option is not found